# How can I scrape Euribor table from XML and convert it to CSV file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, data-conversion

I am trying to scrape this url https://www.suomenpankki.fi/WebForms/ReportViewerPage.aspx?report=/tilastot/markkina-_ja_hallinnolliset_korot/euribor_korot_xml_short_fi&output=xml and conver it in to a CSV file in PowerShell. I am very new to PowerShell, but would like to know if someone had a solution or an example from similiar scenario, which I could then use to solve my problem.

I have tried this:

```
$doc =New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.load('https://www.suomenpankki.fi/WebForms/ReportViewerPage.aspx?report=/tilastot/valuuttakurssit/valuuttakurssit_short_xml_fi&output=xml')
$doc.Transaction.ChildNodes | Export-Csv "C:\Users\henri" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter:";" -Encoding:UTF8
```

Comment: Use `Invoke-Webrequest` to invoke the URL and then `convertto-csv` and `Export-CSV`

Comment: You need to think what kind of CSV data is needed. XML data is hierarchal, CSV is, as column-oriented, flat.